# Copy,paste and add row when selected and removed when Delete is selected

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I just started with vba.I am busy with a parts order sheet

[image]

I need, in the top picture, if you click the **ADD** button it must copy ex. I26 and L26 to the bottom sheet, to D2 and E2. Then it must go down to the next row.

Question 1: if the person has made a mistake can you code the "**REMOVE**" button to delete that specific row?

Question 2: is it possible to code the control button to change fill colour when it is selected?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a code writing site, but we can provide help to find out what went wrong. Can you add examples of what you tried, and provide additional information on how it failed to meet your expectations?

Comment: Both issues can be solved with vba, but I think you're likely to get better responses in stackoverflow than superuser as these are programming questions.